# Streaming media to WiiMC

Tags: 12.04, samba, vlc, streaming, video-streaming

I have spent a couple of days at this issue, and I'm seething in frustration.

I am trying to stream my movies/music to my Wii console.

When I had Windows, this was all too simple: create a profile with username and pass, know your IP, and select directories to share.

- Now I tried something similar to this with Samba, but it just doesn't work. I tried everything. I tried a few tutorials which ended up making ubuntu freeze and refuse to boot (re-install).
- I also tried seriio, which I couldn't get to work after numerous tutorials.
- Finally I tried vlc with vlc-shares. I had some success. I got it to run, but it will only let me stream from /root not expansion drive :( . I tried to put a movie on my SSD and it didn't work anyway.

I am at a total loss as what to do now. I am by no means a total newbie at networking, just new to Linux. I would appreciate it greatly if someone could guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Could you please [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/376880/edit) and add the precise error you got when you tried to use vlc-shares from a non-/root partition?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing the GUI for Samba (if you haven't already) by searching for "samba" in the Ubuntu Software Center, or by installing the "system-config-samba" package with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install system-config-samba
```

Then start start samba with the following command:

```
sudo system-config-samba
```

Then create a new share, give it a folder and make it accessible to "everyone". Then create a new user.
Select your own username in the drop-down menu "Unix Username"
Then enter a Windows username and Samba password. These two, along with your computers IP-address are the settings you enter in WiiMC under SMB Share.

(Keep in mind that you can't stream videos with a quality higher than 480p, because the Wii simply isn't strong enough.)